# Find user in Linked IN API Who does not share his /her feed

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Is it possible to find the user who does not share his feed? Any option available to get that record. Because I got exception when I fetch user updates of my connection.

Comment: "Is it possible to find the user who does not share his feed?", do you mean the users in your connection?

Comment: yes i want to find who has hide their feeds in my connection

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm sure you've already seen the linked in api docs but I'll link the appropriate docs here:

http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields

I don't think you can do exactly what your after but perhaps your problem is that you're assuming a field will be sent that a user can hide.

from the docs:

> Not all fields are available for all profiles. The fields available depend on the relationship between the user you are making a request on behalf of and the member, the information that member has chosen to provide, and their privacy settings. You should not assume that anything other than id is returned for a given member. If a member has chosen to opt out of data sharing, requests for data return as private for id and last-name. (This means id is not a unique field.) This affects data retrieved from all APIs, such as a person's connections, recommendations, people search, network updates, or status updates. Code defensively!

For example the docs refer to a person's `first-name` field as so:

> This field might return a value of private for users other than the currently logged-in user depending on the member's privacy settings

There doesn't appear to be an api setting that actually comes out and says a user has turned off sharing their feed.